# How to fit the exponential function using Matlab curve fitting tool?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a table with 2 column, c1 and c2 in Matlab. I want to use the Curve Fitting Tool to fit the exponential equation into my data.

Right now I have this in my code:
*cftool(c1,c2);*

this code is going to open cftool and fit the **polynomial** curve! However I want it as an **Exponential** curve! How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
f = fit(x,y,'exp1');
```

You can also customize:

```
myfit = fittype('a*u+b*exp(n*u)',...
            'problem','n',...
            'independent','u');
```

to use `f=fit(x,y,'myfit');`
[You can read about it here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/exponential.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#btpaend-7)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to have the data to be fit in your workspace and choose the **X data** and **Y data** first. Then the dropdown menu will show "Exponential" as an option. From [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/exponential.html):

> 1. Open the Curve Fitting app by entering `cftool`. Alternatively, click Curve Fitting on the Apps tab.
> 2. In the Curve Fitting app, select curve data (**X data** and **Y data**, or just **Y data** against index).
>      Curve Fitting app creates the default curve fit, `Polynomial`.
> 3. Change the model type from `Polynomial` to `Exponential`.

To see the code used by [`cftool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cftool.html) for fitting your data, select **File > Generate Code** after you've configured all of the options and are satisfied with the results. You can then use and modify this code for your application instead calling `cftool`. In the case of a simple exponential fit, it looks like the [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) function is used with options specified via [`fittype`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html) and [`fitoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fitoptions.html).

Comment: But the point is I want to do this from the code. Not manually!

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using `cftool` in the first place! It's meant for interactive fitting. But you can use `cftool` to generate code: File > Generate Code... You can see how the generated code does it (via [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html)) or you could also try [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html).